# Could not initialize SpringHibernateFactory from Web Service

Tags: web-services, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts

I have a Dynamic web application that uses Struts 1.3 + Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4.0 and it all works fine when trying to use it from the web project. When I created a WebLogic Web Service that is added to an EAR and also a Web service client to consume and I try to retrieve java objects from the database I get: **Could not initialize class com.multivision.ehrms.crud.impl.SpringHibernateFactory**

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Could not initialize class com.multivision.ehrms.crud.impl.SpringHibernateFactory
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/}exception:<message>Could not initialize class com.multivision.ehrms.crud.impl.SpringHibernateFactory</message><ns2:stackTrace><ns2:frame class="com.multivision.ehrms.service.data.BaseDataService" line="unknown" method="getDataRetriever"/><ns2:frame class="com.multivision.crm.service.data.QueryDataService" line="unknown" method="retrieveAllQueries"/><ns2:frame class="com.multivision.crm.ws.CRMdata" file="CRMdata.java" line="22" method="retrieveAll"/><ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl" file="NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java" line="native" method="invoke0"/><ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl" file="NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java" line="39" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl" file="DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java" line="25" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="java.lang.reflect.Method" file="Method.java" line="597" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker" file="WLSInstanceResolver.java" line="92" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker" file="WLSInstanceResolver.java" line="74" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2" file="InvokerTube.java" line="151" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandlerImpl" file="EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.java" line="268" method="invoke"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube" file="SEIInvokerTube.java" line="100" method="processRequest"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="866" method="__doRun"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="815" method="_doRun"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="778" method="doRun"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="680" method="runSync"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="403" method="process"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="532" method="handle"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="253" method="handle"/><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="140" method="handle"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter" file="WLSServletAdapter.java" line="171" method="handle"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke" file="HttpServletAdapter.java" line="708" method="run"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject" file="AuthenticatedSubject.java" line="363" method="doAs"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager" file="SecurityManager.java" line="146" method="runAs"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper" file="ServerSecurityHelper.java" line="103" method="authenticatedInvoke"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3" file="HttpServletAdapter.java" line="311" method="run"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter" file="HttpServletAdapter.java" line="336" method="post"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet" file="JAXWSServlet.java" line="95" method="doRequest"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet" file="AbstractAsyncServlet.java" line="99" method="service"/><ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="820" method="service"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction" file="StubSecurityHelper.java" line="227" method="run"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper" file="StubSecurityHelper.java" line="125" method="invokeServlet"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl" file="ServletStubImpl.java" line="300" method="execute"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl" file="ServletStubImpl.java" line="183" method="execute"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="3717" method="wrapRun"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="3681" method="run"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject" file="AuthenticatedSubject.java" line="321" method="doAs"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager" file="SecurityManager.java" line="120" method="runAs"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="2277" method="securedExecute"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="2183" method="execute"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl" file="ServletRequestImpl.java" line="1454" method="run"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.work.ExecuteThread" file="ExecuteThread.java" line="209" method="execute"/><ns2:frame class="weblogic.work.ExecuteThread" file="ExecuteThread.java" line="178" method="run"/></ns2:stackTrace>

Could not initialize class com.multivision.ehrms.crud.impl.SpringHibernateFactory
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.multivision.crm.ws.CRMdataPortBindingStub.retrieveAll(CRMdataPortBindingStub.java:176)
    at com.multivision.crm.ws.DataConsumer.main(DataConsumer.java:12)
```

Like I said, the SpringHibernateFactory has no problem initializing when using the web project, but when I expose the project using a web service and client then SpringHibernateFactory cannot initialize. Can anyone understand this problem?

Comment: How it's run from web project?

Answer (score 0):

Did your spring context start when server startup ? Can you find this kind of output in your console ?

```
[ContextLoader ]  Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[XmlWebApplicationContext ]  Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 05 09:34:47 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
[XmlBeanDefinitionReader ]  Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
```

Try to add this in your web.xml otherwise

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

No link with your problem but why to use a java EE server if you're using spring ? Tomcat should be sufficient, and if you really need a Java EE server then use CDI and EJB container instead of spring

Comment: I don't get that output on startup but I do have that listener and ContextLoaderListener in web.xml. I dug deeper and it seems that the JNDI lookup for the datasource doesnt work in the webservice, although it works in the web app. Why could that be?

Comment: i need additional information like webService class and the way you get the hibernate SessionManager